# Unable to authenticate mongodb from springboot application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using a spring boot application to connect MongoDB instance. We have enabled authentication on MongoDB with following roles

> roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "{{ mongo.database_name }}" }
>
> roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "{{ mongo.database_name }}" }

We are providing the credential using conf files

> data:
>
> mongodb.uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1/testDB
>
> mongodb.authentication-database: admin
>
> mongodb.username: 'admin'
>
> mongodb.password: 'admin'
>
> repositories.enabled: true

While booting the application, we are inserting in a particular collection. However during the insertion, it tried to create index and fails with following exception

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
 { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDB to execute command 
 { createIndexes: \"ws.city\", indexes: [ { name: \"code\", ns: \"testDB.ws.city\", unique: true, key: { code: 1 } } ] }" , "code" : 13};

FULL stacktrace:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [XYZRepository]: 
>    : Error creating bean with name 'XYZRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
>    nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
>    { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDB to execute command 
>    { createIndexes: \"ws.city\", indexes: [ { name: \"code\", ns: \"testDB.ws.city\", unique: true, key: { code: 1 } } ] }" , "code" : 13};
>     nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , 
>     "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDB to execute command { createIndexes: \"ws.city\", indexes: [ { name: \"code\", ns: \"testDB.ws.city\", unique: true, key: { code: 1 } } ] }" , "code" : 13}; 
>     nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XYZRepository': 
>     Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
>     { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , 
>     "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDB to execute command { createIndexes: \"ws.city\", indexes: [ { name: \"code\", ns: \"testDB.ws.city\", unique: true, key: { code: 1 } } ] }" , "code" : 13}; 
>     nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDB to execute command
>      { createIndexes: \"ws.city\", indexes: [ { name: \"code\", ns: \"testDB.ws.city\", unique: true, key: { code: 1 } } ] }" , "code" : 13}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
>       at com.app.ws.WSApplication.main(WSApplication.java:22)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Ideally, I understand that the role which should be required for an application to interact with mongodb should be "readWrite".

- Does it expects a different role?
- Does the spring tries to create index automatically while inserting and require higher / different role?
- Anything which we are missing in this scenario?

We are using mongoDB latest version : 3.2.4
Springboot 1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the authentication database to testdb like `mongodb.authentication-database: testDB`.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934427/connect-to-multiple-mongo-db-hosts-and-authenticate-using-a-different-database-i) worked for me, as mine was a standalone mongo, refer [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), For a standalone that enforces access control.

```
mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/?authSource=admin
```