# Connect to multiple mongo db hosts and authenticate using a different database in spring boot

Tags: java, database, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a java application which integrates with mongo db. I happen to have 3 mongo db hosts (all with same port) and they have to be authenticated using a separate db other than the db my application uses. For eg: "admin" is the authentication database name and "contenttest" is the db my application wants to connect to. I have credentials as well (username and password). I tried the following uri to connect, but its not working in spring boot application.

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://content_rw:<secret password>@a.mongo.db:27017,b.mongo.db:27017,c.mongo.db:27017/contenttest?wtimeoutMS=300&connectTimeoutMS=500&socketTimeoutMS=200
```

I am getting error saying authentication is unsuccessful with the following error logs.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='content_rw', source='contenttest', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapInMongoSecurityException(SaslAuthenticator.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:66) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:162) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:109) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:46) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server a.mongo.db:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$000(SaslAuthenticator.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

stacktrace contains similar exceptions for other hosts as well.

I need some help to achieve authentication using a separate db ("admin") and use a different db ("contenttest") when using 3 mongo hosts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) the connection string URI format is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

The `/database` part is described as:

> Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection
>   string includes authentication credentials in the form of
>   username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection
>   string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin
>   database.

You have set up the URI like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://content_rw:<secret password>@a.mongo.db:27017,b.mongo.db:27017,c.mongo.db:27017/contenttest?wtimeoutMS=300&connectTimeoutMS=500&socketTimeoutMS=200
```

In your logs we can see the line:

```
Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='content_rw', source='contenttest', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
```

In `MongoCredential.java` the `source` is described as:

> the source of the user name, typically the name of the database where
>   the user is defined

So it looks like you have set up the authentication database as `/contenttest` and not as:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

I think you should remove the database name from the URI and probably `spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database` property, because `admin` database is used by default.

Also, look at this:

[image]

This line should be interesting in terms of setting up the application database:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
```

Comment: Thanks @cbartosiak it helped... i think documentation dint specify that authentication database shouldnt be used as a property along with uri since we have to give authentication database in the uri and other database through separate property.. anyways thank you again :)