# Exception authenticating MongoCredential and Uncategorized Mongo Db Exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

**I am getting this error socket exception raised by this connection while running my application.**

```
INFO 5231 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to 192.168.0.2:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.**

    org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='campbell', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='campbell', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:138)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2756)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2666)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2409)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:214)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='campbell', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}

    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server 192.168.0.2:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }

**I have declared properties in application properties-**
spring.data.mongodb.database=dbname
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.password=*******
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.0.2
```

Login credentials are right still I am getting this error.
Exception authenticating MongoCredential also I am getting  Uncategorized Mongo Db Exception

Please help me out!

Comment: Have you specified an `authenticationDatabase`? It's likely you're authenticating against a different database as to what the user is in. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934427/connect-to-multiple-mongo-db-hosts-and-authenticate-using-a-different-database-i

Comment: After adding this line - **spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database = admin** in application properties. Now it is working properly. Thank You!

Comment: That's great! I've added an answer to help future SO users. Please accept this as the correct answer if you feel this helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As per [#46934427](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934427/connect-to-multiple-mongo-db-hosts-and-authenticate-using-a-different-database-i), setting `spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin` would probably fix your issue.

The default database in MongoDB is `test`, therefore, it's likely you are attempting to authenticate against the `test` database. Switching to the `admin` database (the common place for users to be created), might fix your issue.

Comment: You made my day

Comment: This didn't work for me but what did was to add the below option to the connection string:


`authSource=<auth_db_name>`

Comment: You saved my day. Sweet..!

Comment: In my case was the exact opposite.  After removing it, it worked.

Comment: @NachoMezzadra that means your user is not part of the admin database, but part of another database.

Comment: i can use the following command to directly login but not via the application.yml in springboot .. cmd: mongo --port 27017 -u "user" --authenticationDatabase "piggymetrics" -p   while springboot: spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=piggymetrics

Answer (score 29):

You could try this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:passwod@localhost/test?authSource=admin
```

Comment: It solved for me!

Answer (score 4):

```
Add user admin into your database. 
Open installed folder and open the mongo.exe file and run below command : 
use admin
db.createUser(
{
user: "admin",
pwd: "admin",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
{ role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
{ role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
}
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Put these configuration in your application properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host= YOUR_HOST like 192.168.x.x
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.password=PASSWORD
spring.data.mongodb.database=DB_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement other answers - I experienced this problem because Mongo was running on my **local machine** and in **Docker** simultaneously. These instances were both listening on the default `27017` port and I was connecting to my local Mongo instead of the one from the container.

If you are connecting to dockerized Mongo - try to temporary shut down the container and find out if any process is also listening on `27017`. If indeed there is such process - make sure you don't need it and then terminate ([Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux),[Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311842/windows-kill-process-by-port-number)).
You may also want to remove terminated processes from autostart so they won't appear again after reboot ([Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services),[Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/460076/disable-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line)).

Answer (score 0):

> Give username and password along with the url explicitly.This will solve the issue.
> Check out my project from [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/abhisek-mohanty-3a2241235_connections-project-java-activity-7067515774147444736-BX2y?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) everything you can get by exploring.

```yaml
 spring:
      data:
          mongodb:
              uri: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/
              username: <username>
              password: <password>
              database: <database>
```