# Tomcat on port 8080 failed using Spring boot Java

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am beginner of spring boot. when i run the spring boot application i ran into the problem with The **Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. Spring boot**

i don't how to solve the problem. i have install mysql when i ran the mysql it port also 8080. so how to sort out the problm.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

    The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
    
    Action:
    
    Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Comment: So you have MySQL running on port 8080? That is your problem than. Stop the MySQL service and you can run Tomcat on 8080.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Kill Process By PORT Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311842/windows-kill-process-by-port-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like 8080 port is already used by some other process.

Change the port of spring-boot tomcat port by adding the `server.port=8090` in `application.properties`.

Change 8090 to any port you want to use.

Comment: error gone. but localhost/8090 but This site can’t be reached

Comment: You mean localhost:8090 with : and not / ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 8080 port is already used by some other process.

Change the port of spring-boot  `server.port=8090` in `application.properties`.

You can change your application run server port any port number to if that port number would not belong to any other process on your computer.

and another thing if you use IntelliJ idea to develop, accidentally close your IDE without proper way this error may have occurred {personal experience}.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily required to change the port, you can just end the process of it to release it in your spring application

1. Open cmd as administrator and enter the following commands:

`netstat -year | findstr 9330`

2. Once you find the process number, type it in the highlight of the following command:

`taskkill /F /PID <Process ID>`

3. The result should appear as follows:

SUCCESS: The process with PID < Process Id > has ended.